# Error booting after installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I get this this error after installing Windows 8:

[image]

> The Group Policy Client service failed the sign-in.
>   The universal unique identifier (UUID) type is not supported.

Previously I used to use Linux but now after installing Linux or Windows nothing works on my Dell laptop.

After a few times, if I again want to log in into Windows, then the same error was shown.

I can use my laptop with a live boot Linux and I have full access to the HDD and all of its partitions.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you able to boot into safe mode at all?

Comment: no, safe mood also fails

Comment: What happens when you boot into safe mode?

Comment: Its immediately restarts the pc